# How do I parse a piece of text from a previously-clicked link or page name?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm working on an online art auction. The bid updates are all manual. When a person clicks "Bid Now!" via a button below the piece, a simple form pops up in a new window. The form is on a page with a little bit of information, including the title of the piece they bid on (the title then becomes the subject of the email I receive from the form). My question is, can I parse the title of the piece onto the pop-up form page FROM the previous page using javascript or jQuery? The script would have to Get the piece of text from the previous page somehow. I'm envisioning something like this:

```
<a href="../bid-form.html" name="lastname" value="TitleOfWork"><img src="image.html"/></a>
```

The pop-up form page (shown in fiddle) could Get "TitleOfWork" and place it in the first line of text. (But that value would change, so I'd need to call it a variable).

My other alternative (how the the previous programmer set things up) is to make a form page for every piece of work, because the titles are all different. I REALLY don't want to do that because it's just impractical. There are hundreds of works in this auction.

I feel like this is a much simpler solution than I'm making it out to be... I'm just self-taught and don't know many of the basics. Hope this makes sense!

*EDIT:

This is the javascript I'm trying to work with (i'll include it directly on the bid-form page, but I need the "value" to be a variable (aka, the "value" I defined in the link that opened the form, which would be the title of the work):

```
<script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined")
  {
  // Store
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "[variable]");
  // Retrieve
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("lastname");
  }
else
  {
  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
  }
</script>
```

Here's an updated link to the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/UVkVt/2/

Comment: Do you know anything about [`JQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/) or [`AJAX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you need to use localstorage instead.

Add html id and value into your code

```
<a href="../image.html" name="#TitleOfWork" id="TitleOfWork" value="yourValue">Bid Now!</a>
```

In your javascript file, you need to grab value from id, save and retrieve it using localstorage.

save

```
localStorage.header = $("$TitleOfWork").val();
```

retrieve

```
$("#header").setText(localStorage.header);
```

your popup html code

```
<h1 id="header"></h1>
```

P.S: you need to use jquery

Comment: Do I save and retrieve in the same script? And I store that script in a separate linked .js file? This appears like it's going to work for me, as I need the value to be a variable. But, I know javascript a little better than jQuery, so I edited the post with the code I'm trying to work with. Maybe you could take a look?

Comment: Use same script. I suggest you use jquery for your project. You can show me what you have done.

Comment: I added the edit! Does it make any sense? Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this...!